# Best practice to gather data across multiple fragments before db write

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

Android application using .net/Xamarin. I have several fragments in a view pager. If I were to have some data collected on each fragment in the pager incrimentally, what is the best way to gather all the data as I go and only write to the db once, at the end? I am using a sqlite db. But, lets say for example there are two fragments in the pager. First fragment collects user name, first and last name. Then, a next button takes them to the second fragment for address and phone number. After they are done, they click save and then I can write to the db one I have gathered all of the info.

Sure, I could write to the db after each fragment, but is that really the best practice? I dont think I want to pass the data from fragment to fragment. That might seem like a way to go with the above example but I dont think it scales well, for example if I end up later with 5 fragments collecting data.

I have been thinking about a singleton class. I have read that they should be avoided at all costs but maybe this is an application suited for them? I could create a singleton with all my properties and as I go through the fragments and build data, they are saved in the singleton. At the end, I basically write the singleton data to the db and clear it out, ready for the next time. I dont think I have to worry about thread safety in this use case or at least, I can write it so it is not an issue.

Is that the way to go? Other thoughts or ideas?

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A singleton is used when you need to manage a resource, such as a database connection. In this case, I would recommend against using a singleton just to store data.

The way you propose to use the singleton isn't much different than passing an object around, the only difference being that with a singleton, you can make a request for the object you are populating.

The way you could do it, would be to have an object representing each fragment. This would allow you to initialize and have fragment dependent logic (such as validation) within a given class.

You would then have a more generic object, one that will hold the information from all the fragments which will be eventually saved to the DB. You can pass this object around from one fragment to the next, and each fragment populates the bits it is interested in.